# SSIS OLE DB Data Source Input

Tags: ssis

I have an OLE DB Data Source in my SSIS package where I'm wanting to run this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM vw_DimWorker WHERE AsOfSourceDtm > ?
```

and that variable is a `DateTime`.  The value comes from a different data source where I just want to run this query:

```sql
SELECT last_update from Last_Updates WHERE table_name = 'worker'
```

I can create the source item and the sql task item but I'm not sure how to hook up the date from the second query shown so that I can then use it as the variable on the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use variables in your package.  When you run the first query have result set = single row/value.  Then on the result set tab for your first query, set the results of the query to populate your variable.

Then in your next SQL task, setup a parameter (separate tab in the SQL task) and set the parameter to your variable you just populated.

Link to Example in MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

But this may be better step by step instructions:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/